# Is PHP international?

Tags: php, localization

Can you create websites with Chinese characters in PHP?

UPDATE: Perhaps I should have said - is it straight forward. Because some languages like Java make it extremely easy. Perhaps localisation in PHP isn't as easy as Java???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes on both counts. Read [this guide](http://www.herongyang.com/PHP-Chinese/) on building Chinese websites in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to know what you are doing...

Read this [article](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets) (search for *PHP's Problem with Character Encoding*) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/11/28/php_i18n.html